# Iam trying to execute Spring 3.0 and Ajax , json

Tags: jquery, maven, spring-mvc

Iam having dependencies like:

jackson-mapper-asl
1.9.12

jackson-mapper-lgpl
1.9.12

jackson-mapper-lgpl
1.9.12

while executing the one Request Mapping , iam getting below exception.

java.lang.StackOverflowError    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:111)  at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:22)   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.HierarchicType.(HierarchicType.java:38)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to show code, but it looks like you might have infinite recursion happening, or at least your call stack is getting too large.